# No se reflejan los errores en hoja html de validaciónes con Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Estoy realizando la validación con mis atributos de mi clase donde tengo set y get, los mensajes de error los tengo en mi messages.properties y mi controlador quien envía el objeto atributo al Html pero al dar submit carga la pagina normal pero no me muestra los mensajes en el Html.

Si las esta validando por que entra en el `if (result.hasErrors()) { ... }`   pero en el html no se reflejan los errores del message.properties

messages.properties

```
NotEmpty.CBindingDTO.nombre = Ingrese el nombre de usuario
```

OBJETO:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class CBindingDTO {
    // @NotEmpty(message = "Ingrese el nombre") --> Asi tampoco refleja el message en el html
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Controlador:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import com.example.demo.clase.CBindingDTO;

@Controller
public class BindingDTOcontrol {

    @GetMapping("/bin")
    public String bin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new CBindingDTO());
        return "binding";
    }

    @PostMapping("/bin")
    public String binpost(@Valid @ModelAttribute CBindingDTO dto, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:" + result.getFieldError());
            model.addAttribute("form", dto);
            return "binding";
        }

        return "binding";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">
            <span th:text="${title}">Our App</span>
        </h1>
        <div th:if="${generalError != null }" th:text="${generalError}"
            class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"></div>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/bin}"
            th:object="${form}" method="post">
            <fieldset class="row g-3">
                <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                    <label>agrupacion</label> <input class="form-control" type="text"
                        th:field="*{nombre}" id="agrupacion" placeholder="agrupacion">
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}"
                        class="form-text"></div>
                </div>
                <br /> <br />
                <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success mb-3" type="submit"
                        id="submitButton" th:value="Guardar">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El binding del objeto form de la vista no se está realizando correctamente en el controlador.

Prueba a cambiar en el controlador el siguiente método:

```
public String binpost(@Valid @ModelAttribute CBindingDTO dto, BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Por la siguiente declaración donde se indica el nombre del objeto asociado al formulario denominado "form":

```
public String binpost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("form") CBindingDTO dto, BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Más información sobre la etiqueta @ModelAttribute en inglés en el siguiente enlace:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423262/what-is-modelattribute-in-spring-mvc